# Terminal function for collections in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose we have a list of some int values(positive and negative) and we have a task to double only positive values. Here is a snippet that produces the desired result:

```
val list: List[Int] = ....

    list.filter(_ > 0).map(_ * 2)
```

So far so good, but what if the list is very large of size N. Does the program iterates N times on filter function and then N times on map function?

How does scala know when it's time to go through the list in cycle and apply all the filtering and mapping stuff? What will be result(in terms of list traversing) if we group the original list by identity function for instance(to get rid of duplicates) and the apply map function?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the program iterates N times on filter function and then N times on map function?

Yes. Use a view to make operations on collections lazy. For example:

```
val list: List[Int] = ...
list.view.filter(_ > 0).map(_ * 2)
```

> How does scala know when it's time to go through the list in cycle and apply all the filtering and mapping stuff?

When using a view, it will calculate the value when you actually go to use a materialized value:

```
val x = list.view.filter(_ > 0).map(_ * 2)
println(x.head * 2)
```

This only applies the filter and the map when head is called.

Comment: `withFilter` is not limited to `List`. All `Traversable` support it.

Comment: and what about groupBy, flatMap and other functions? I suppose it's impossible to use view in this case, because of the new type of collection being created. How do you think?

Comment: Your intuition is correct about `groupBy`: even if you call view on the list first using groupBy calculates the grouping eagerly as a `Map`. `flatMap` on the other hand maintains the view (and its laziness).

Answer (score 2):

> Does the program iterates N times on filter function and then N times
>   on map function?

Yes, for a `List` you should use `withFilter` instead. From `withFilter` doc:

```
Note: the difference between `c filter p` and `c withFilter p` is that
      the former creates a new collection, whereas the latter only
      restricts the domain of subsequent `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`,
      and `withFilter` operations.
```

Comment: what if we do a `partition` and then manipulate on two collections created(for example do `zip`, `map` and so on). Is it possible to not iterating over the collection each time?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a `map` after `filter`, you can always using `collect` instead:

```
list.filter(0<).map(2*)
```

to

```
list.collect{ case x if x > 0 => 2*x }
```

Comment: or simply use for comprehension : `for (e <- list; if e > 0) yield e * 2`